# Is it possible to grab a hash table value similar to an array without a key?

Tags: powershell

If I have a hash table like this...

```
$theHash = @{"dog"="mean"; "cat"="nice";"bird"="annoying"}
```

If I had an array, I could usually do something like $theHash[0] to grab dog or mean. Is this possible with hash tables as well to grab a specific value, or do I need the key?

I want to iterate through a list of hash table values and grab both the key and value based on certain keys.

Comment: If you input the key wouldn't you already have the key?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The point of a hashtable is so you can quickly retrieve items by using keys. If you want an array, then just use an array.

Comment: but an array you have to set the value ahead of time. i just read that a hash table is better to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the point of the key is to access it by key.

You can get an array of the values with `$hash.Values`. From that, you can filter like you would any other array with `Where-Object` for instance.

If you want to grab the key and value based on certain keys or values, then do something like this:

```
foreach($pair in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
    $pair.Name
    $pair.Value
}
```

So within the loop you can use and `if` or `switch` or whatever conditionals you want to figure out what you want to keep.

Comment: so $theHash.values turns it into an array? no way.. that's awesome. and it auto assigns the values to it? so it would be like a 3 dimensional array... like =... 0 | dog | mean ?

Comment: it seems the values only takes the values out.. obviously from the name duh i shouldve thoguht of that. anyway to combine it to a 3 dimensional like above?

Comment: @simon not sure what you mean by 3 dimensional. Can you show it as though you would want to access a single element?